# "It's time something was / were done about the problem."

Tags: mandative

> It's time something **was** done about the problem.

It is a sentence from Murphy's "Grammar". Using **was** confused me, for me it should be **were**. It looks like this clause is in *subjunctive mood*—something that is unreal / imaginary, and in that case you always use **were** for any object.

Unless, of course, it is not the subjunctive mood, what would knock me down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @tchrist's Google Ngram shows, it is established idiom, beyond the reach of mere grammatical logic.

And anyway, it's mandative; if it **were** subjunctive, it should be present subjunctive, *It's time something **be** done.*

ADD:
Jespersen, *A Modern English Grammar on Historical Principles*, Vol 4 (I omit notes indexing citations.):

> **9.6.** After *it is (high) time* it is usual to use the preterit. Originally this was in the subjunctive because it was looked upon as hypothetical, but as in the majority of instances there was no formal difference between the subjunctive and the indicative, and as the hypothetical element was not so clearly before the mind as in conditional sentences, the indicative came to be used.

Comment: I don’t think it would ever be normal to use the present, whether subjunctive or indicative, but I cannot tell you why, for I do not know.

Comment: @tchrist It never *has* been normal; but the present subjunctive is enjoying a renascence, and if the "color commentators" latch on to it anything can happen. *Should be* might emerge, too.

Comment: @tchrist In fact, *be* is [**in the running**](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=time+that+something+be+done%2Ctime+that+something+were+done%2Ctime+that+something+was+done&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=5&share=), in US texts

Comment: From the excerpt you quote: "Originally this was in the subjunctive because it was looked upon as **hypothetical**" [Emphasis added] -- Since it's talking about it being hypothetical, I think this is referring to the past subjunctive. How do you know it's actually talking about the present subjunctive? And what's the hypothetical element it is referring to, then?

Answer (score 5):

Both forms certainly occur, but the hypothetical *were* form is less common.  Here’s a [Google N-gram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=time+something+was+done%2Ctime+something+were+done&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=5&share=):

[image: ngram of was/were done]

There are [plenty of *were done* examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22time%20something%20were%20done%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en) to be had, but they are still in the minority.  Attribute it to most people not being particular careful about this sort of thing. Many of them just don’t know about it, and it isn’t part of their speech.